# jquery ajax type GET question

Tags: jquery, ajax

I hava a simple question. I have a server running which take actions according to parameters in the url.

Example: if I type in browser: http://localhost:8081/Edit?action=renameModule&newName=Module2

This works correctly.

I would like to know the equivalent jquery ajax method to perform the same thing

I have tried

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/Edit',
    type: 'GET',
  data:'action=renameModule&newName=Module2
});

It is not working.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This could be due to some [cross domain restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You can perform AJAX calls only to resources which are hosted on the same domain/port as the HTML page performing the request. If this is not the case you could also try this call:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/Edit', 
    type: 'GET', 
    data: { 
        action : 'renameModule', 
        newName: 'Module2' 
    }
});
```

or using the [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function:

```
$.get('http://localhost:8081/Edit', { 
    action : 'renameModule', 
    newName: 'Module2' 
});
```

Comment: It was the cross-domain issue. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

why can't you use

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/Edit?action=renameModule&newName=Module2', 
    type: 'GET' 
});
```

edit : in the example you supplied, you're missing a ' from the end of the data param, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: It was the cross-domain issue. Thank you for your help!!